# Android - Activity is not closed by Back button

Tags: android, android-activity, service, back-button

I wrote the activity(called by service) to make popupwindow and finished both activity and service when I click the button on screen or pressing back button. Here's the code.

service:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Intent popupIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmPopup.class);
      popupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

      startActivity(popupIntent);
      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class AlarmPopup extends AppCompatActivity {
  PopupWindow popup;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              onShowPopup();
          }
      };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
  }

  public void onShowPopup() {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_popup, null);
      popup = new PopupWindow(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
      popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

      popup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
      view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
  }

  Button.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(AlarmPopup.this, AlarmService.class);
          stopService(i);
          popup.dismiss();
          finish();
      }
  };

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          Intent i = new Intent(AlarmPopup.this, AlarmService.class);
          stopService(i);
          popup.dismiss();
          finish();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

When I pressed the button on the screen, everything goes well that I expected. But when I pressed back button, it only closes the popup window, and the service & activity are not finished. Service and Activity are finished when I clicked back button once more, but I want to finish all of them by 1-click.

I also tried this instead of onKeydown(),

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmPopup.this, AlarmService.class);
    stopService(i);
    popup.dismiss();
    finish();
}
```

But it also doesn't working. What do I need to do on this situation?

Oh, one more thing. The log 'W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.' is printed when I clicked back button. Is this the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back event is consumed by popup window , You can try finishing activity onDismiss of popup , or try using dispatch Key events .

```
  popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDismiss() {
          Intent i = new Intent(AlarmPopup.this, AlarmService.class);
          stopService(i);
          finish();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some will try to convince you this is not a good solution (for some reasons), but I think you can get your way, to force your Service to stop, by adding this to your code, after **finish()**:

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Best.

**EDIT:**

I start my service on **onCreate**, by doing this:

```
intent = new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class);
    startService(intent);
```

Then, on my closing methods, I kill process. Works here.

Comment: I think we differ how we start our services, me here, and you there. Did some editing in my answer, maybe can help. Thank you and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Popup window catch the backpress event, you should call `finish` in popup window's KeyEvent listerner